# Post Persist creating another entity after one is persisted

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm, doctrine, zend-framework2

I want to be able to automatically create a user profile after a user registers. I have attached a post persist function that creates a user profile object, but I don't have access to an entitymanager to persist the object. What is the best way of going about this?

```
//user.php
/**
 * @ORM\PostPersist()
 */
public function PostPersistAction()
{
    //create a user profile when a user is created.
    $userprofile = new Profile();
    $userprofile->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime("now"));
    $userprofile->__set('user', $this);

    $em = $this->getEntityManager(); //doesn't work because getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine..') fails
    $em->persist($userprofile);
    $em->flush();

}
```

Comment: Why is fetching the EntityManager from the ServiceLocator failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

```
/**
 * @ORM\PostPersist()
 */
public function PostPersistAction(LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs)
{
    $entity = $eventArgs->getEntity();
    $em = $eventArgs->getEntityManager();

    if ($entity instanceof User) {
        //create a user profile when a user is created.
        $userprofile = new Profile();
        $userprofile->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime("now"));
        $userprofile->__set('user', $this);

        $em->persist($userprofile);
        $em->flush();
    }

}
```